# calling MPMoviePlayerController from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

I would like to use MPMoviePlayerController as embedded. The real issue is i am making a small library which MPMoviePlayerController handles to play video  and if API is pushing some preroll  advertisements i am stopping video and starting to show ad video immediately.

From now, i was able to do it with fullscreen but, company needs embedded version of that player which going to be play in UIView or an tableviewcell.

Shortly :

MPMovieController is created another class  as moviePlayer

ViewController is the basic  UI Class that developers going to call moviePlayer class and embed video  into ViewController's UIView

Best Regards.

---

Onder.

Comment: You just have to get an instance of the MPMoviePlayerController's view controller. Are you using a UINavigationController?

Comment: I am using  [self presentViewController:vsp animated:YES completion:^(){ block method in order to show present UI as MPMoviePlayerController as full screen but it's not working for embedded .

Comment: What's `vsp` in `presentViewController:`?

Comment: vsp is the MPMoviePlayerController class view

Comment: Oh, OK. Well, you can definitely put a MPMoviePlayerController within a UIView. Could you post the code you've tried already so we can tell you what you're doing wrong?

Comment: I can play in UIView but the scenario should be like that : MPMoviePlayerController is in another UIViewController(Player.m) which i need to call that class and add movieplayer.view in to userprederred UIView's element . Assume that Main.m is the current view that developer going to show moviePlayer with calling Player.m  and Player.m  needs to know that which ViewController's UIView should be movie player's going to be add as subview .

Comment: @LyndseyScott I would like to put the codes over here but it's a bit looking like a Library because i am preparing this library in order to developer can use it. That is why i need to call MPMoviePlayerController from another class.  But my main problem is in moviePlayer class [addSubView:theMoviePlayer.view] method. I need to add in to UIView which inherit in ViewController  class.

Answer (score 0):

I 've solved async task from another class with moving in appDelegate. So classes which has async task can be process and callback anytime and when finish i am posting notification.